# passing arguments to javascript through cscript on the command line

Tags: wsh, jscript

I have a small command line JScript routine that I usually run from the command line using cscript in Windows.  I'd like to be able to pass in arguments hopefully along the lines of...

```
%:>cscript doSomethingToFile.js FileInQuestion.txt
```

Any insight on how to do this?

Comment: [Check `WScript.Arguments`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156618.aspx).

Answer (score 15):

From Bernard Marx

1. Create this JScript file, save it in C directory, (as xx.js)

**xx.js**

```
alert = function(s){WScript.Echo(s)}

var arg = WScript.arguments(0)
alert(arg.toUpperCase() + " now upper case")
...
```

1. Open the command prompt, and type

(assuming at C:> prompt):

```
C:\> windows\wscript.exe xx.js "apples and bananas"
```

Comment: C:\Windows\wscript.exe? maybe C:\Windows\System32\wscript.exe C:\xx.js "apples and bananas"